# My Android Thing Raspberry Pi is throwing a javax.net.ssl.SSLException when sending request to Firebase Storage

Tags: raspberry-pi, firebase-storage, android-things

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi using Android Thing to Firebase Storage.  I keep getting the attached exception.  The Storage Rules are completely public no auth needed.  Has anyone else received this error and found a workaround?

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x95683f00: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:824)
 at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:76)
 at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
 at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
 at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.writeUtf8(RealBufferedSink.java:58)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.writeRequest(HttpConnection.java:172)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.writeRequestHeaders(HttpTransport.java:76)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:265)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at brv.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1386)
at brv.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:269)
at brp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:53)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbrc$zza$zza.zzjN(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbrf.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqw.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqw.zzd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzaba(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: is there anything else in the Logs? Usually if a firebase feature doesn't work it spits out error logs before the stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check:

1) Make sure that you have network (you likely already do since you're trying to reach Firebase) e.g. 'ifconfig'

2) Make sure that DNS is working e.g. 'ping ...' something

3) Check system time to see if it's synced to current rather than 1970 e.g. 'date'; you can manually set it current as a workaround

If for any of the above reasons that time is not set properly, your SSL cert probably won't work.

See working code in the Doorbell sample here: https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I know the app/device has a good internet connection since I can successfully connect to the firebase database and google mobile vision api within the app.  It's only the firebase-storage api that is throwing this error.  Has anyone has success connecting to firebase-storage from their Android Thing app on a pi device?